# How do I use the index to identify a Todo that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

basically i need to remove a ToDo that was clicked, but because there is no unique id to the ToDo..it removes all of them.. i tried UUIDV4 but i was unsuccessful adding it to each ToDo

***App.js***

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    input: "",
    todo: [],
    completed: false
  };

  handleRemove = (id) => {
    const remove = this.state.todo.filter((todo) => 
    todo.key !== id.key);
    this.setState({todo: remove});
  }

...
 <TodoList 
          todo={this.state.todo}
          rmv={this.handleRemove}
        />
```

***TodoList***

```
const TodoList = ({todo, rmv}) => {
    const todoBuild = todo.map((todo, index) => (
      <Todo 
        todo={todo} 
        key={index} 
        rmv={rmv}/>
    ))
    return <div> {todoBuild} </div>
};
```

***Todo***

```
const Todo = ({todo, rmv}) => {
    return (
        <div className='todo'>
            <p>{todo}</p>
            <button className='btn-rmv' onClick={() => rmv (todo)}>x</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to add an id by UUIDV4? You can use the `index` of the todo but having a unique id is always a good idea. Maybe you can share the code where you are adding your todo item.

Comment: Don't use the index of the array, when creating a new todo, you can use timestamp to make an attribute called `key` and when click on a delete todo, yo can get the id and filter your array and delete the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array is ordered structure, so you can rely on items index, which will stay the same even after serialization/deserialization.

**NOTE** (thanks to **@devserkan**): Spread operator (`...`) used in this example creates shallow copy of the array, in case if you work with nested arrays - please, `splice` can modify original array (which is what you never want to do). Please, use methods to create a deep copy of the array (`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`, lodash library method or etc.) or substitute `splice` function with `Array.filter`.

**Remove function**

```
handleRemove = (id) => {
    let todo = [...this.state.todo]
    todo.splice(id, 1);
    this.setState({todo});
  }
```

**TodoList**

```
const TodoList = ({todo, rmv}) => {
    const todoBuild = todo.map((todo, index) => (
      <Todo 
        itemIndex={index}
        todo={todo} 
        key={index} 
        rmv={rmv}/>
    ))
    return <div> {todoBuild} </div>
};
```

**Todo**

```
const Todo = ({todo, rmv, itemIndex}) => {
    return (
        <div className='todo'>
            <p>{todo}</p>
            <button className='btn-rmv' onClick={() => rmv(itemIndex)}>x</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I know it is not a problem here but I'm a little bit hesitant suggesting `splice` since it makes in-place changes. Spreading the original state just creates a shallow copy. For nested properties, this also changes the original state. I like the `filter` method. `const todo = this.state.todo.filter((_,i) => i !== id );`

Comment: @devserkan Sure, good point. According to the code structure, i'm assuming that there shouldn't be any nesting inside of array, but i will mention that in the reply.

Comment: Great! Yes, in this example it is not needed, even using `filter` seems a bit overkill but whenever I see `splice` I automatically think about that. But, one more thing :) Actually `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` has some gotchas. This does not work if the data has something non-serializable. For example, if an object has a method as a property, we lose it. So, this is why I like using `map` or `filter` and manipulate the state without changing the original one.

Comment: @devserkan That is why i made it as one of the possible options :)